# Named parameters in queries for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query, parameter

ALL,

I'm trying to find a proper syntax to do the following:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM foo WHERE foo.id = :id;
```

(the query above is written as in SQLite).

The "normal" query would be written as:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM foo WHERE foo.id = ?;
```

The first query is written with the named parameter, the second - with unnamed.

Google gives me the syntax for Stored Procedures and/or Functions, but what I am looking for is a `SELECT` query with the named parameter.

TIA!

EDIT:

The second syntax called a query with parameter and it using `?`. So, when I write a C++ code I will be using BindParameter() ODBC syntax.

However with the first query n MS SQL Server, what syntax is correct?
I used the syntax that is used in SQLite for the query with the named parameter. And my question is for the proper syntax for SQL Server?

IIUC from the responses the proper SQL Server syntax is:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM foo WHERE foo.id = @id;
```

Which means I will need to declare the variable named id, bind it to the prepared query and then execute it.

To answer Tibor question - no, the question is specifically for SQL Server. The DB Engine has t understand the syntax and I'm not sure how to properly write the query. My question is independent of client tool.

To answer Charlieface question - I am using plain `SELECT...` query, not a stored procedure or a function. As stated - that was what Google search gave me. What I am looking for is how to properly write such query (not sp or func) for SQL Server so that DB engine will understand it.

EDIT2:

So, my full code will look like this (for SQL Server):

```
std::string query = "SELECT a, b, c FROM foo WHERE foo.id = @id;";
SQLExecute( stmt, "DECLARE @id" ... );
SQLPrepare( stmt, query.c_str()... );
SQLBindParameter();
SQLExecute();
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking for?...there is no such thing as a parameter when not in the context of a procedure or function. Perhaps you want to declare a variable, e.g. `DECLARE @id INT = 123;`. Then you can use that variable in your query? Also you tagged your question as *sql-server* which is for Microsoft SQL Server specifically. Did you mean to ask a question for Microsoft SQL Server or a different database system like SQLite?

Comment: There's probably a client tool involved here. SQL Server is an engine and has no understanding about client tools, parameters and such. A client tool might use some syntax like ?, @1 to ask the user for input and then replaces this symbol with the input. But this is completely done client-side - SQL Server has no involvement in this.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi Not sure what you mean, you can pass parameters to an ad-hoc batch also, using `sp_executesql` and this is what nearly all drivers do. They do not normally concatenate values in directly

Comment: Which client software are you using? And are you using a stored procedure or just an ad-hoc query?

Comment: @Charlieface But sp_executesql is a stored procedure. I. e, something is executing a proc and passing values into its parameters. Regardless of semantics, I think we need some more context from Igor.

Comment: @Charlieface, please see the edit. I hope I made it more clear. Let me now if its not.

Comment: @J.D., please see the edit. I hope I made it more clear. Let me know if its not.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi, please see the edit. I hope I made it more clear. Let me know if its not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as mentioned in the comments, when you're talking about a general query, not in the context of a function or procedure, the term *parameter* doesn't exist - but perhaps what you really mean is *variable*, just the same for your goal.

In that case, to declare a variable in SQL Server's (T-SQL) syntax, you'd want to do:

```
-- @ denotes it's a variable, followed by the name of the variable, and then the type after, optionally followed by = and a value if you want to set the variable during declaration (but not required)
DECLARE @id INT = 123;
```

If you choose not to set the variable during declaration then you can set it to a value later on using the `SET` keyword like so:

```
SET @id = 123;
```

Then you can utilize that variable within the same scope as your query like so:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM foo WHERE foo.id = @id;
```

Full picture:

```
DECLARE @id INT;
SET @id = 123;

SELECT a, b, c FROM foo WHERE foo.id = @id;
```

Comment: please see my second edit. Is it a proper syntax? Thx.

Comment: @Igor Now that you've presented your full code, it appears you really need help with C++ (or whichever procedural language you're using). That question is probably better suited for StackOverflow since it's not really as much of a database question. But anyway, are you hoping to set the variable dynamically with C++ code or will you be setting it to a hard-coded value in SQL?

Comment: the variable will be set dynamically. However the `SELECT` syntax is what I'm after for SQL Server. Otherwise preparation/execution of the query will fail as DB engine will simply not recognize the query and fail.

Comment: @Igor Your `SELECT` query is valid syntax, yes. Your line of code that says `SQLExecute( stmt, "DECLARE @id" ... );` doesn't specify the data type of the `@id` variable, so you'll most likely need to do that as part of the `DECLARE` statement, e.g. `SQLExecute( stmt, "DECLARE @id INT" ... );`. If that syntax is all you're wondering about then you should be all set now, otherwise if you need help setting the variable dynamically that will definitely be a C++ specific question you'll need to ask on StackOverflow.

Comment: yes thats what I ws looking for. Thank you.